# How to add a value to a dictionary using reflection in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following Dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, double> averages = new Dictionary<string, double>();
```

Now I want to use reflection to add two additional values. I can retrieve the field info, but what else do I have to do?

```
FieldInfo field = ProjectInformation.SourceManager.GetType().GetField("averages");
if (field != null)
{
    //what should be here?
}
```

Comment: why do you want to add the values via Reflection??

Comment: @Tim Schmelter for unit testing purpose

Comment: This will make for fragile tests. If you can, revise your tests or system under test so that the tests do not need knowledge of implementation details.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Thanks, but I now. I prefer to make fragile test over changing the code just for testing reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to get the field and values just for Unit Testing consider using Microsoft's [PrivateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Its there so you can check the internal state of data members during unit testing if you need to, which appears to be what you are trying to do.

In your unit tests you can do the following:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
PrivateObject privateAccessor = new PrivateObject(obj);
Dictionary<string, double> dict = privateAccessor.GetFieldOrProperty("averages") as Dictionary<string, double>;
```

Then you are free to get and set any values you need to from the Dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

```
MethodInfo mi = field.FieldType.GetMethodInfo("set_Item");
Object dict = field.GetValue(ProjectInformation.SourceManager);
mi.Invoke(dict, new object[] {"key", 0.0} );
```

Comment: You don't need to use Reflection after you have the reference to the dictionary.

Comment: @reneI can't find the method GetMethodInfo(..) on a FieldInfo.

Comment: @Roflcoptr for the sake of history used the FieldType property :-)  ... sorry ...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(field != null)
{
   field.GetValue(instance);
}
```

Comment: that will only give you the dictionary